# Get events count by last minute and event level

Tags: elasticsearch, events, count

I have parsed events with field like "level" (DEBUG, INFO, ERROR, FATAL). How to retrieve events count by last minute and level type = ERROR?

[screen from Kibana](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foCUn.png)

I'm trying like that:

```
    curl -XGET 'mysite.com:9200/myindex/_count?pretty=true' -d '
   {
   "query":{
      "term":{
         "level":"error"
      }
   },
   "filter":{
      "range":{
         "_timestamp":{
            "gt":"now-1m"
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

Comment: You have provided almost 0 details about the issue. What is your index mapping? Give examples of actual documents. Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 3):

You must have timestamp on your events.If yes, write a count aggregate query on events with query filters of level type and range timestamp(elasticsearch do support range on time/date field with 'now' parameter).
confusing part is you did't mention what kind of count you want.Total event count or you want to count by type or some name parameter(in that case use terms aggregation on that parameter).

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/mapping-date-format.html#date-math

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "level": "trace"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "range": {
                                "timestamp": {
                                    "gt": "now-1m"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I need total event count that has field "level"="error" by last minute.

Comment: then just do a simple query with date range filter, level=error filter(use bool filter) and you will get the hits count.